# How to load the thumbnails for the pictures stored in particular folder (or with IDs)?

Tags: android, mediastore

I have an activity with a GridView where I want to show thumbnails for images taken with standard camera activity and stored in a particular folder. This activity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks interface and here's its onCreateLoader() method's code

```
...
...

private static final String APP_PICTURES_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Pictures to process";
private String[] mProjection = {
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID,
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA,
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID
};

private SimpleCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;

...
...
...

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String[] imagesProjection = {"_id", "_data"};
    Cursor imagesCursor;

    imagesCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            imagesProjection,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " LIKE '%" + APP_PICTURES_DIRECTORY_NAME + "%'",
            null,
            null
    );

    String[] imageIds = new String[imagesCursor.getCount()];
    int i = 0;
    while (imagesCursor.moveToNext()) {
        imageIds[i++] = imagesCursor.getString(imagesCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
    }

    String[] selectionArgs = {TextUtils.join(",", imageIds)};
    return new CursorLoader(
        JourneyAlbumActivity.this,
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        mProjection,
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND + " = " + MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND +
                " AND " + MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + " IN (?)",
        selectionArgs,
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + " DESC"
    );
}
```

But the result is empty in the result. If I remove this clause

```
... + " AND " + MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + " IN (?)"
```

Everything's ok but in the result I have a grid of thumbnails of all the images taken with camera while I need only those from my specific directory. How do I select thumbnails for images from a particular folder or with particular IDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, to make it work you have to insert your parameter directely inside the clause :

```
return new CursorLoader(
    JourneyAlbumActivity.this,
    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    mProjection,
    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND + " = " + MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND +
            " AND " + MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + " IN ("+TextUtils.join(",", ids)+")",
    selectionArgs,
    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + " DESC"
);
```

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
System.out.println("getFilePaths()");
        File fileDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator +"folder_name"+ File.separator + AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM);
        if(!fileDir.exists()){
            System.out.println("fileDir does not exist");
            try{
                fileDir.mkdir();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
            System.out.println("fileDir DOES exist");
        File directory = fileDir;

        // check for directory
        if (directory.isDirectory()) {
            // getting list of file paths
            File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();

            // Check for count
            if (listFiles.length > 0) {

                // loop through all files
                for (int i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++) {

                    // get file path
                    String filePath = listFiles[i].getAbsolutePath();

                    // check for supported file extension
                    if (IsSupportedFile(filePath)) {
                        // Add image path to array list
                        filePaths.add(filePath);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // image directory is empty
                Toast.makeText(
                        _context,
                        AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM
                                + " is empty. Please load some images in it !",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context);
            alert.setTitle("Error!");
            alert.setMessage(AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM
                    + " directory path is not valid! Please set the image directory name AppConstant.java class");
            alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            alert.show();
        }
```

Comment: Umm... Where is the Loader, where MediaStore query or at least anything similar to loading data from content provider? How do you suggest to check if underlying content is updated which loaders are designed for? I don't think it has anything to do with my question.

Comment: I'm just suggesting an alternative method I've used to great success in the past. I have never used MediaStore so I can't help you with that. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, honestly. But it's really not what I need. I need my app to reflect the changes of data like when I take new photo with camera and it's saved to the directory and I'm back to the grid activity new data (thumbnail of just taken photo) should immediately appear there which is working exactly like that already just for all the images on the device while I need only particular photos to be loaded.